# build python program with extensions using py2exe

Tags: python, c, py2exe, recipe

I'm having a hard time finding py2exe recipes, especially for cases that require c extensions.

The following recipe works fine without the "ext_modules" part.  With it I get "NameError: name 'Extension' is not defined.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import os

s = os.popen('svnversion')
version = s.read()
f = open('cpa_version.py', 'w')
f.write('VERSION = "%s"\n'%(version.strip()))
f.close()

setup(console=['cpa.py'],
      options={
        'py2exe': {
            'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'pytz', 'MySQLdb', 'pysqlite2'],
            'includes' : ['PILfix', 'version'],
            "excludes" : ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg',
                          "Tkconstants","Tkinter","tcl"],
            "dll_excludes": ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                             'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 
                             'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                             'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll']
            }
        },
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
      # how to build _classifier.c???
      ext_modules = [Extension('_classifier',
                               sources = ['_classifier.c'],
                               include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                               libraries = ['sqlite3'])]
)
```

_classifier.c includes the following

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the small error created by forgetting to import Extension, I ran into other errors stating a problem with the -lsqlite3 flag.  Turns out I needed to follow the steps outlined here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/82135-sqlite-questions.html

1. Download sqlitedll-3_3_7.zip and sqlite-source-3_3_7.zip from sqlite.org/download.html
2. Extract sqlitedll-3.3.7.zip and then run from the command line:

   dlltool -D sqlite3.dll -d sqlite3.def -l libsqlite3dll.a
3. Place libsqlite3dll.a (just created) in the MinGW lib directory.
4. Place sqlite3.dll in your system path (c:\Windows\System32\ worked for me)
5. Extract sqlite-source-3_3_7.zip and place sqlite3.h in your MinGW include directory.
6. When you link, you will need to supply the parameter: -lsqlite3dll (this meant changing libraries=['sqlite3'] to libraries=['sqlite3dll'])

...After that the build worked.

Here's the setup file again:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import os
import numpy

setup(console=['cpa.py'],
      options={
        'py2exe': {
            'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'pytz', 'MySQLdb', 'pysqlite2'],
            'includes' : ['PILfix', 'version'],
            "excludes" : ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg',
                          "Tkconstants","Tkinter","tcl"],
            "dll_excludes": ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                             'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 
                             'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                             'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll']
            }
        },
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
      ext_modules = [Extension('_classifier',
                               sources = ['_classifier.c'],
                               include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                               libraries = ['sqlite3dll'])]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

to

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
```